# Reshape output of TeXForm into one-line string

Tags: string-manipulation, latex

I am using Mathematica to generate some Matlab code. In order to have a bit of documentation I would like to have a commented line in the Matlab file which holds the Latex form of the original expression. However, there is an issue with linebreaking.

An example:

```
test = TeXForm[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}]
```

Looking at `test` and also `ToString@test` reveals a couple of linebreaks which are nice for formatting and export to actual Latex documents but not for my purpose. The reason is that I would like to use a string (one line - which may be very long) like `"% Expression: " <> ToString@TeXForm@test` in the Matlab file ("%" creates comments in Matlab code), which fails because of the linebreaks (only the first row appears as a comment).

So I thought of operating on

```
test2 = ToString@FullForm@ToString@test
(* "\\left(\n\\begin{array}{ccc}\n a & b & c \\\\\n d & e & f \\\\\n\\\end{array}\n\\right)" *)
```

where I would then easily replace/delete the `\n`. Yet, to no avail - see:

```
StringDelete[test2, "\n"]
(* "\\left(\n\\begin{array}{ccc}\n a & b & c \\\\\n d & e & f \\\\\n\\\end{array}\n\\right)" *)
StringPosition[test2, "\n"]
{}
```

So I wonder how can I remove the linebreaks from `TeXForm` and ideally also replace the `\\` with `\` in the final string. This also seems to be a bit tricky because of Mathematica's [special characters in strings](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialCharacters-StringsAndCharacters.html).

The final result of something like `customTeXForm[test]` should be the string
`\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a & b & c \\d & e & f\\\end{array}\right)`

Comment: does `StringReplace[ToString[test], { "\n" -> ""}]` work?

Comment: @kglr In fact, it does. I would bet that I tried it before I asked the question here - but anyway... Thank you very much :)

Comment: in case you decide to keep the question, i posted the comment as an answer.

Comment: @kglr Am I missing something or does `StringDelete[ToString[test], "\n"]` work as well?  This whole things seems like a simple mistake.

Comment: @MrWizard, yes it does!  Just didn't occur to me:(

Comment: I would use `ToString[expr, TeXForm]` to get the strings instead of `ToString[TeXForm[expr]]`.

Comment: Must have been distracted it seems. Don't know why I missed that simple thing.

Comment: @CarlWoll is there any reason why this should be better or is it just a matter of taste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
StringReplace[ToString[test], { "\n" -> ""}]
```

> [image]